# Number format type REAL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question about the format of numbers `REAL`.

I have a column with this type and after I insert 8 numbers for this column, it doesn't let me to save.

Example: `11406760`

When I try with a 7 digit numbers like `1140676`, it lets me to save the data.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? REAL is supposed to be floating point data type.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2012

Comment: What are you using to insert the data? A user interface or a query?

Comment: Can you post the error/message that it displays after entering an 8-digit number?

Comment: Better define `NUMERIC` type with necessary precision.

Comment: I am using:DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON SubParcels;

UPDATE SubParcels
SET Area = 11406760
WHERE SubparcelID = 857960; 

ENABLE TRIGGER ALL ON SubParcels;   The result i am taking is: "1.140676E+07"

Answer (score 0):

If I read [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) correctly, REAL is a synonym for FLOAT(24), which has a precision of 7 digits.

This means that while a column of this type does support values up to about 10^38, it only keeps about 7 most significant digits of that value. So for an 8 digit number, the final digit may not be stored correctly.

Do you *really* need a REAL (=floating point) value for this column (maybe check out [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)), or rather some integer type?

Comment: I just need to make it REAL, I don't want to change the type. Is there any chance to stay with REAL and to accept 8 digit numbers without changing the type?

Comment: @user2568960 - no, without changing the type, you can't use more significant digits. Is there any reason to use REAL instead of INT?

Comment: ah ok. yes, the reason is because I need to change it in application too,that's too much